# Vulkan: how to write non-brittle tests-cases

Tags: vulkan

I'm working on adding unit-tests to my toy Vulkan renderer.
The current approach that I'm thinking of implementing is like so:
Each unit-test function (the test) is called twice, once to setup the test-data and render the frame, followed by another call to validate the rendered frame.

My issue is that this setup seems brittle. I have to first render a frame, save the image to file, and then compare the rendered frame to what's on file. If anything about the test changes, then I have to resave the image for later comparison.

Question: Is there another, less brittle, way that I could set this up? Specifically, I'm not too crazy about having to compare raw images.

Comment: That doesn't seem "brittle"; it seems non-functional. You're executing code to generate data, then executing the same code again to generate data, then comparing those executions. Won't the results *always* be the same?

Comment: The saving of the image to disk is done once, when the test is initially created or the test changes. Thereafter, the image stays on disk, unmodified. This serves as the comparison data for the test(s), which will be ran on a regular basis.